# Opencart - Notice: Undefined index: saving in

Tags: php, jquery, e-commerce, opencart, vqmod

I'm using Opencart 1.5.6.1.

In this page:
[http://jefferson.com.my/test/index.php?route=product/results&category=[75]&path=0&filterProduct=1](http://jefferson.com.my/test/index.php?route=product/results&category=%5B75%5D&path=0&filterProduct=1)

There's error in some products, 
SAVE Notice: Undefined index: saving in /home/jefferso/public_html/test/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog_view_theme_pav_fashion_template_product_category.tpl on line 147%

It's because I install a mod that display the discounted percentage.
It doesn't have problem displaying in category page, product page and home page, but if you try the filter on the left (tick T-shirt) which resulted in the page above, the error will show out.

I don't know how to deal with that cache file, and the theme developer doesn't want to help at all.

Comment: Please mention here theme vqmod file code. Go to your site source > vqmod > xml > & find yourtheme.xml file(may be it xml file name will theme name).

Comment: Hi, the theme doesn't have a VQmod. But the show saving percentage mod is a vqmod can be found here: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=4498&filter_search=special%20percentage

Comment: Hi, I have check it extension. but, it is working fine. Please mention here your category.php file code. (catalog > controller > product > category.php)

Comment: Hi Harnish, you can check the category.php file here: http://pastebin.com/p0NfVF4e

Comment: it link is not working.

Comment: Weird, please try this:
http://chopapp.com/#aouqhuqg

Comment: Or this dropbox link: https://db.tt/E609X3XD

Comment: Sorry, miss-understanding Here, I have realized. You have use third party extension for Filter By. So, According to your this link(http://jefferson.com.my/test/index.php?route=product/results&category=[75]&path=0&filterProduct=1) is not category page. This link page is new custom page. So, **Here, You need to find it page name. what is name of it new page file?(page name of Filter by extension)** & let me know. so I will send code it page related. Go to > catalog > controller > product > & then check new file name(May be results.php).

Comment: Hi Harnish, can you download the mod here, with all the files because I don't know where to look, really appreciate your help. https://db.tt/uxzkcbbe

Comment: I'm voting to close because _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your source > vqmod > xml > & then find & open "webvet_percentage_to_specials_v6.xml" file > & then below code add in bottom of the page above `</modification>` tag. > & then check it.

```
// FILTER PAGE
<file name="catalog/controller/product/results.php">

    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
        'special'     => $special,
        ]]></search>

        <add><![CDATA[
        'saving'     => round((($result['price'] - $result['special'])/$result['price'])*100, 0),
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>

<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/result.tpl">

    <operation>
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[
        <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
        ]]></search>

        <add><![CDATA[
        <br /><span style="color: red;">SAVE <?php echo $product['saving']; ?>%</span>
        ]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
```